# MongoDB - Updating the collection periodically during application start-up

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo, mongobee

I have a requirement where i need to create one mongoDB collection. That collection will hold NAICS code and description which will be updated by NAICS Association every five years. They release in excel and we need to update our collection. This collection will expose API to front-end, they use it for type-ahead function to auto-complete for user.

Every five years once, i need to update few rows and add few rows. So what will be the best approach in mongoDB. I am pretty new and getting confused which is better approach.

1. Using MongoBee and having changelog / changeset to add/ update the rows every five years once.
2. Using MongoBee, delete all the rows and add newly all the rows every five once.
3. Have DBA team to update or add every five years once.

Please let me know what will be the correct approach in above list or what you have. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script to do the job, add a README file explaining how to use the script to the person who would be tasked to invoke it 5 years from now.